# Hide input tag made by js after click icon

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

i made an input tag using js after click an icon. I want to hide input tag after i click icon again.. here is my js code

```
const icon = document.querySelector('.menu li:nth-child(1)');

icon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'search');
    input.placeholder = 'search';
    const ul = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const li = document.querySelector('.menu li:nth-child(1)');
    ul.insertBefore(input, li);

});
```

Comment: You could use `style.visibility` or `style.display`, depending on whether you still want it to take up space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can go two ways...

1. Create the search input element as a permanent DOM element and hide/unhide it as necessary.
2. If you want to keep the element dynamic, try coding it like this...

   ```
    icon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const search_input_elem = document.getElementById("search_input");
    if (search_input_elem){
        search_input_elem.remove();
    } else {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'search');
        input.placeholder = 'search';
        const ul = document.querySelector('.menu');
        const li = document.querySelector('.menu li:nth-child(1)');
        ul.insertBefore(input, li);
    }
   ```

   });